# Posting rendered html page to a web service? Best way to transmit data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, actionresult

I am creating a web service that will send an email via Amazon SES. I want to separate the service(API) from the actual application that is going to take in data to be sent. So all I want to send the service is the to address, subject line, and rendered html body of the message. The service in this case is going to be an MVC action result method in C#, and I would like to post the information in JSON. Typically when I post data to a webservice, the data is pretty small and concise.

So my question is, is there a better way to submit html to a webservice as opposed to just sending JSON formatted like this? Would it be a good idea to base64 encode it? Or is there a better way to do this all together?

Post body.

```
{
   "to" : "asdasd@email.com",
   "subject":"hello",
   "body":"<html><body><h1>asdasd</h1></body></html>"
}
```

My model would look something like.

```
public class EmailMessage
{
    public string toAddress { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
}
```

Then my action result would look something like...

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SendEmail(EmailMessage msg)
 {

      //Send an email

 }
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You may also want to post this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about size of request an response, you can add GZip support.

```
public class CompressAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

            string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

            acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

            HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP") && response.Filter != null)
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
            else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE") && response.Filter != null)
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
        }
    }
```

then in your controller add attribute to the action or the controller itself:

```
[Compress]
public class AccountController : Controller
```